# Relativity and speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, velocity, observers

This might be a stupid question but anyway here it goes.

Let's say that I move towards a friend of mine at 75% of $c$ relative to the earth. Then, he moves towards me at the same velocity.

When we cross, which velocity would I measure him going relative to me?

Answer (score -1):

This is just a direct application of the relativistic velocity addition formula
(u + v) / (1 + uv/c^2)

Just substitute u = .75c and v = .75c .
You will get the answer .96c

Comment: Please look for a duplicate before posting a new answer.  This kind of question has been asked and answered multiple times.

Comment: AHEM: _hundreds_ of times . . .

Comment: @m4r35n357 maybe not *hundreds* (on this site) but possibly multiples of 10.